# Ubuntu 20.04 Internal Error every login (tracker-miner-fs)

Tags: 20.04, login, crash, tracker

Whenever I login to Ubuntu, I get this error:

[image: Tracker-Miner-FS Crash Pop-up]

Some background:

1. This Ubuntu installation is from a fresh-install, not an update
2. I believe Ubuntu is updated as I always let updates perform its thing when it prompts
3. As advised by the prompt, I did restart twice and still get the error message

Searching AskUbuntu returns some issues related to tracker-miner-fs, but theirs seem to have their CPU pegged at high utilization which is not the case for mine (CPU currently at ~3%).

If other details are needed, please do tell as I am not quite knowledgeable with what tracker-miner-fs does.

Also some follow-up questions:

1. Am I right to assume that this is akin to Windows Search/Cortana/Indexer?
2. Do I need it if I know where to locate any of my files?
3. Can I completely disable this safely?

Thanks!

Edit: I could not make more meaningful tags like "tracker-miner-fs", "miner", etc. as it requires 300 rep

Comment: Here is what tracker-miner-fs does: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tracker-miner-fs.1.html

Comment: Yes tracker is a gnome project: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker and i have this problem all the time, similar to spotlight with apple search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu updated itself again and the issue does not reoccur anymore as of this writing.

**Edit**: not sure how to close this thread or mark this as "answered"

**@mods**: kindly delete if this thread is irrelevant, thank you!